# Practices with database in QGIS

Tags: qgis, database

I would like to store some specifics data (customer information, etc.) into my QGIS project. The aim is to be able to automaticly use these data later when I make some exports. Some of these data are unique to a project, others can be used for several projects.

These data are not geographics data:

- List value for list in attribute fields
- Customer data : name / adresse / invoice etc.
- Step/state of my project.

There are several types of data:

- Data that serves to fill my attributes fields features.
- Data that serves to match the QGIS project with my company data (customers, missions, etc.)
- Data that serves to complete the QGIS project : I would like to use same field for every project. These data will able me to rank & classify my projects.

My first idea was to store them into a XLS or in CSV. What are the best practices or is there any alternative?

Comment: Your question is too broad. How much data do you have? How often does it get updated? What is your goal(!)? QGIS can do almost anything, recommendations on best approaches can only be given if we know what you want to achieve and what possible limitations are.

Comment: I've tried to complete my original post as you suggested ! I'm not sue about how often they will be update, but I can say: "often".

Comment: "Best" questions are generally *off-topic* in GIS SE because they encourage discussion, which is contrary to the Focused question/Best answer model used here. Neither CSV nor XLS can qualify for "database" stature, so the question title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's already in a database: Keep it there!

QGIS has a wide range of supported databases and can load the data just as well as images or geographic map data (actually, most geographic formats use specialized databases internally).

Simply connect them using the DB Manager / Add Data wizard and query the data you need whenever you need it for your analysis or export processes. This ensures you'll always have up-to-date information and can completely avoid an export/import/update workflow.

Check
[the official QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html)
for how and what kinds of data you can load.

Comment: Does the QGIS's project own a table that in which I could store datas and create some fields?

Comment: You can use QGIS to create a table, but usually that would be stored as an external data source (eg CSV). It's possible to make a "temporary scratch layer" but that will normally be wiped clean when you close the project. There is a plugin that will make temporary layers permanently saved, although I'm not sure whether it keeps them in the project file or just saves them to a normal external datasource.

Comment: I'd really recommend a separate, proper database for this and loading that in QGIS. Even if it's just a SQLite. Working on file-level for data that "changes often" and needs further manipulation (calculating fields etc.) will have bad performance and integrity issues are almost sure to happen down the road.